Why does English distinguish between 'must' and 'have to', particularly in the negative?
In English, there's a (minor) semantic difference between 'must' and 'have to', particularly when negated. For example, 'you must do this' and 'you have to do this' mean roughly the same thing, but 'you must not do this' and 'you don't have to do this' have different meanings. In other languages, this doesn't seem to be a distinction that's explicitly made. In German, for instance, in all of the above sentences you'd use the verb 'mussen' and the meaning would be implied by context.
This is also the case for other modal verbs, such as 'can' and 'to be able to'. Where does this oddity come from, and why does English do it?

My German is rusty, but if I remember correctly "you must not do this" = "Du darfst nicht das tun" and "you don't have to do this" = "Du musst nicht das tun", so it does not seem correct that they are both translated with "mussen" and the meaning is only implied by context.

I wouldn't call this a semantic difference so much as a syntactic one: negation cannot go above modals. In other words, when combining a modal (something that goes at the T node, like "can", "must", "will", "should") with a negative, there's only one place a negative can go: you have to put it after the modal, not before.
(Note that how this is interpreted semantically is not quite as consistent as the question implies: it's correct, at least for me, to say "you can also not do that" to mean "it is possible to not do that", as opposed to "you can't do that" meaning "it is not possible to do that". It's marked, but allowed. This is also how it works in German, to my understanding.)
This is one of a few limits on modals that sometimes get in the way. For example, we can't generally combine multiple modals: standard English doesn't allow *"she will can do this" to mean she'll have the ability in the future, but doesn't have it now. So when we want to express these meanings, we use normal (non-modal) verbs to paraphrase the meaning without the syntactic limits on modals.
Since "have to" and "be able to" aren't modals, just verbs (V) with infinitive complements, they're not subject to those restrictions, and you can either negate that verb itself ("he does not have to do it") or negate the infinitive inside it ("he has to not do it"). This gives you more control over the semantics, showing explicitly which thing is supposed to be negated. (And similarly, this lets you combine them with other modals, and say "she will be able to do this" and "she will have to be able to do this" and so on.)
